# How to save information properly

Tags: model-view-controller, int

I'm new to coding, and I'm currently getting started with writing own programs.
I've decided to structure my little program in model, view, and controller.
Buton I'm running into a problem I don't know how to solve.

I've made a basic "program", to depict my problem:

```
public class View {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller c = new Controller();
        c.method();
        System.out.println(c.getI());

    }
}

public class Controller {

    public int getI() {
        Model model = new Model();
        return model.getI();
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setI(i);
    }
    public void method(){
        Model model = new Model();
        model.method();
    }
}

public class Model {

    private int i;

    public void method(){
        i = 25;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

I know my class View is no view class at all, but it'll be sufficient for my example.

I tried to communicate from view to model, through the controller. Please correct me if I'm doing it wrong

I'm first calling the method "Method"m which I defined in my model-class. This method sets my int I to 25.
But afterwards, I'm printing out that "i", but I'm getting 0, as if it wasn't given a value.
What am I doing wrong?

In my actual little program, I'm trying to save a list. When I then try to get that list, I'm getting a nullPointerException.

Comment: You keep creating new instances of your model.  Anything you change in one instance won't be changed in another instance.  Consider an analogy... A car rolls out of a factory.  You put your bag in the trunk of that car.  Moments later another car rolls out of the factory, completely identical to the first one.  If you open the trunk of the second car, do you expect to see your bag there?  Why not? - Basically you either need to retain your model instance so there's only one being used, or you need to persist your data somewhere and read from that persistence.

Comment: So, how do I do it? Shall I make my model static?

Comment: You can put values in static fields if you like, sure.  Of course, then you'd only ever be able to have one value stored.  "How do I do it" is a bit broad, it depends on what you want to do.  Currently you're "writing a program", which doesn't exactly describe much in terms of desired functionality.  We can appreciate that you're new to this, and it's great that you're trying.  But it's not clear to me what specifically we can do to help.

Comment: I want to read-in Excel-files, store the information in vocabulary-object, which are stored in Lists. I then want to access them later on in my program.

Comment: Well, you've got a ways to go then.  You'll need to look into examples of how to read from Excel (in I'm guessing Java), build an object to store your data in, etc.  If any given instance of the program should only ever be interacting with one Excel file at a time then static values may indeed be a reasonable approach.  Or perhaps you could read/write the Excel data for each operation, treating the Excel file like a database, not needing to keep a copy of everything in your program.  There are a variety of approaches you can take.  But just describing what you want to do is too broad for here.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Appreciate it!